# Debugging the launch screen

Tags: ios, autolayout, launch-screen

I am getting ready to submit an app to the store and one of the last things I have to do is make certain that the launch screen looks decent different devices, which in my case is all extant versions of iOS running on iphones.  The problem is both while building to my device or the simulators, the launch screen only displays for a fraction of a second if not instantly going by and I can't really diagnosis the autolayout problems in the storyboard file.  Is there a way to set a breakpoint at the launch screen or otherwise make the app stop there?

Answer (score 22):

Set a breakpoint in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and launch your app.  It will freeze on the launch image/launch screen.

Comment: Actually, No.  At least in my experience in XCode 9 and up, by the time LLDB stops in the App Delegate (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions), the view hierarchy is already looking at the next view controller

Comment: Works for me in iOS 12, Xcode 10.